# Slackware: print horrible banner

Tags: banner

See banner on old sysV

[image: banner1]

perfect

See on slackware with xfce4 terminal(same on SV4), i can't put the entire image because is very long, put only the last letter

[image: arghh]

What to check? Of course i have tried the -l option,but doesn't work

Comment: We need more information, for example, what's wrong with the second banner compared to the first?

Comment: Yes i use sysvbanner,works perfectly thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for asking this question. It was quite fun looking into it. I don't think there is a standards body governing `banner`.

Here is the LSM for Slack's `banner`:

```
Begin4
Title:      bsd-games
Version:    2.13
Entered-date:   2001-08-30
Description:    Port of most of the games from NetBSD-current.  Games
    included: adventure arithmetic atc backgammon banner battlestar
    bcd boggle caesar canfield countmail cribbage dm factor fish fortune
    gomoku hangman hunt mille monop morse number phantasia pig pom ppt
    primes quiz rain random robots sail snake tetris trek wargames worm
    worms wtf wump.
Keywords:   games, NetBSD
Maintained-by:  jsm28@cam.ac.uk (Joseph S. Myers)
Primary-site:   ibiblio.org /pub/Linux/games
        bsd-games-2.13.tar.gz
Alternate-site: tsx-11.mit.edu /pub/linux/sources/usr.games
Original-site:  ftp.netbsd.org /pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-current/tar_files/src
        games.tar.gz
Platforms:  Requires ncurses (curses/termcap may also work but are no
    longer tested/supported)
Copying-policy: BSD
End
```

`banner` is such an awesome game.

On my *cough* Gentoo system the `banner` program is the one you prefer.  It comes from http://cedar-solutions.com/ftp/software/

Reading the man page for this version I get a sense that you may have opened a can of worms with this question. The author gets a bit salty in the COMPATIBILITY section:

> COMPATIBILITY
>
> From  time to time, people assert that this program is buggy because
>   it doesn't do something that some other banner implementation does. 
>   The behavior of the program is based on what I saw on Solaris and  AIX
>   systems at  the  time  I wrote it in the late 1990s.  I make no claims
>   that the behavior is identical to that of any other contemporary
>   system, especially any non-free system that I may or may not have
>   access to.
>
> If you don't like the behavior, you can either submit a patch, or you
>   can use an alternative program such as figlet.   I  am always happy to
>   accept patches, and I promise to integrate patches promptly if
>   provided.  So far, no one who's complained has bothered to provide any
>   patches, so the behavior remains the same.

Therein lies the answer as well: use figlet with the banner font. http://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.1/misc/figlet/